# minimize makespan: m machines doing n jobs in parallel (with different arrival times)

Tags: algorithm, greedy

- Let n be the number of jobs.1 < n < 1000.
- Jobs are independent.
- Each job arrives at time: Ai ( jobs can arrive in the same time)
- we have m machines that can run in parallel: 1 <= m <= 30.
- each machine can finish a job in time. 1 <= tj <= 20.

**the Goal is to minimize makespan: the time taken before all jobs are finished.**

this is a part of an exercice that requires it to be solved in 1s using a 1GHz cpu. That is: a O(n^2) / O(n^2lgn) algorithm is needed. therefore brute force cannot be used.

---

my first approach was:

```
 for each job,sorted by arrival time, select the machine that finishes first.
```

aka: where max(ai,machine.ready)+Tj is minimal.

the problem is for jobs arriving at 0,1 and machines with times 3,4, for example, the program: choses 3 for 0 and 4 for 1 so it finishes at 5 while if it chose 4 for 0 and 3 for1,it would finish at 4.

+++

-++++

vs

++++

-+++

```
a second approach is to do the same but from the back starting from the last arriving job.
```

but take jobs:0 , 2 and machines 3,7:

- job 2 takes machine 3 which reserves it form t=0 to t=5.
- then job 0 must take machine 7 leading to a 7 finish time

while we can see it's better if we use machine 3 only from 0 to 3 and then from 3 to 6.

--+++

+++++++

vs

++++++

I'm learning from a website that doesn't show the correction until the problem is solved (you pass all the test cases (the input is hidden)) so the problem is guaranteed to have a solution but I have no idea how.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I thought this question would be valid under: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.